# Identifying the key in an Object

Tags: javascript

```
for (var key in obj[i]) {
    dataDump[key] = textField.value;
    textField.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        dataDump[key] = e.source.value;
    })
}
```

I am associating each key in my Object to the TextField which it get's mapped. Now when i change the TextField..... the value get's stored in the `last key` instead of key associated with the textField...

I am changing the `TextField` One... whose key is `dataDump['FirstKeyName']`, but it get's store in the dataDump['LastKeyName']...

Comment: Scope issue, key is out of scope in your event handler

Comment: @Joey: Not at all. The issue is that it remains in scope, so the for loop changes it after the listener is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's normal. You are using a closure. So when you have the callback on change, it searches for key. But you have already finished iterating through obj and key equals the last "entry" of obj.

To correctly associate the key you can do this :

```
for (var key in obj[i]) {
    dataDump[key] = textField.value;

    var callback = function(zeKey){
     return function(e){
      dataDump[zeKey] = e.source.value;
     }; 
    }(key);

    textField.addEventListener('change', callback);
}
```

Comment: the main point is calling function(zeKey){...}(key). When you do so, key, which is a string is copied as a parameter (zeKey) to your anonymous function. Then inside of this anonymous function you return the "true" callback using the copied string zeKey that will not change!

Comment: if you have function test(zeKey){}; and you call test(key); inside of test, zeKey equals the correct key : key. If test returns a function (the callback) which uses zeKey, since zeKey (which is the correct key) is a string, its value won't change.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop you are displaying the TextField is never changed! So in the last key you will have the first textField associating the key with the value in the addEventListenerCode.

The textField var must be altered along with each key in the loop!